# `docker attach` command can't enter into a container unless Ctrl+C or Enter pressed

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I run docker using command:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -it -v $(pwd):/home/root/qadev/ --name loquat bar-qadev-base:latest /bin/bash
```

then I can enter into container automatically. Minutes later I pressed `ctrl+d` or `ctrl+p+q` to exit it.

Now I would like to enter into this `loquat` container again by issuing command:

```
docker start loquat
docker attach loquat
```

But the bash hangs there unless I press `ctrl+c` or an `enter`. I assume it would enter the container automatically without any keystroke. 
Does anybody encounter this issue or know why this happened?

[image]

Here is my Dockerfile for you to reference.

```
FROM ruby:2.2.1
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
COPY ./id_rsa /root/.ssh/

# create default working dir
RUN mkdir -p /home/root/qadev/
WORKDIR /home/root/qadev/

RUN apt-get update \
   && apt-get install -y nodejs --no-install-recommends \
   && apt-get install -y mysql-client postgresql-client sqlite3 --no-install-recommends vim

EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: The only reason I can imagine is the attribute `/bin/bash` in your docker command, which starts a bash shell on your host machine. Since this returns on exit (ctrl+c), the receiving side (docker command) has to wait for it

Comment: Not really. I remove the appending `/bin/bash`  and execute `docker run` again,but this issue still exists.

Comment: Didn't realize it hangs at docker attach.

Comment: how are you exiting are the run command ? If you are doing `ctrl+p+q` then you could attach or exec into the running container the same instance.

Comment: @askb, I used `ctrl+d` to exit the container.  I followed your instruction to use `ctrl+p+q` to exit, but that doesn't help either, thanks.

Comment: Steps 1. docker run 2. ctrl+p+q 3. docker attach or exec (preffered). These steps should work, else better share the dockerfile for others to review

Comment: @askb, I tried your steps, still the same issue. I attached my dockerfile and also made a little change to my posts, hope that helps. thanks.

Comment: this works for me with no issues, `docker attach -it <container id> bash` return a shell. No need to run docker start as mentioned in your post.